# Togglz changes FEATURE_ENABLED column in database

Tags: togglz

I am using JDBCStateRepository with oracle database. During application startup, togglz disables all features (changes all FEATURE_ENABLED to 0 in database) for all features that don't have @EnabledByDefault.

How can I disable this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: That's not the expected behavior. Could you include you dependencies and configuration?

Comment: Turns out it's only happening during Test. TogglzTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod is changing database column based on Feature enum. This is not big deal since I will be using another table for unit test.

Comment: In unit test there is actually a dummy FeatureManager, which shouldn't use a real state repository. Looks like there is something weird with you test setup.